# Mixing page-level elements and column text

Tags: itext7

Trying to tap into iText7 potential, that is in there, but hidden from the developer. I want my text in columns to flow around images that will be placed on page-level (fixed position). Either I'm doing something wrong, or there is a bug in the code. Here is what I have so far:

- open Document for writing
- set document renderer to custom ColumnDocumentRenderer:

  ```
  Class<RootRenderer> cls = RootRenderer.class;
  final Field f = cls.getDeclaredField("floatRendererAreas");
  f.setAccessible(true);

  ColumnDocumentRenderer cdr = new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, new Rectangle[]{
      new Rectangle(36f, 36f, 243.5f, 770f),
      new Rectangle(315.5f, 36f, 243.5f, 770f)
  }) {
      @Override
      protected LayoutArea updateCurrentArea(LayoutResult overflowResult) {
          LayoutArea lr = super.updateCurrentArea(overflowResult);
          try {
              List<Rectangle> list = (List<Rectangle>) f.get(this);
              list.add(new Rectangle(130f, 230f, 350f, 200f));
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              throw new RuntimeException(ex);
          }
          return lr;
      }
  };
  document.setRenderer(cdr);
  ```

This custom renderer adds the rectangle in which I will later place an image to floatRendererAreas field, so that the renderers will know which area to avoid.

- add my content:

  ```
  Div div = new Div();
  div.setBackgroundColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);
  div.setMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
  div.setPaddings(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
  div.setFixedPosition(130f, 230f, 350f);
  div.setHeight(200f);
  document.add(div);

  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
      p.add("Lorem ipsum...");
      document.add(p);
  }
  ```
- unfortunately I get this:

[image: buggy render]

edit: the layouting code is aware of the forbidden area, it just detects it too late, so up to one line is rendered in a wrong way. With y set to 260:

[image: buggy render2]

Probably it looks that the top of the text line is not affected, whereas it should check whether bottom of the text line is not affected as well.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another method to do it? Why is this not part of public/protected API? It could be extremely useful when creating documents.